Calculating output impedance of this op-amp
Let the following schematic from pages 9/10 of "link"

I'm tasked to calculate the output impedance so we used this circuit which is equivalent to the under picture model, with \$R_L = VR1 + 22 \Omega\$ but my question is how can i setup \$V_o ' = 0.5 V_o\$ just by varying the potentiometer VR1 here is my multisim implementation in the following picture:



In your schematic VR1 won't affect the output voltage of the opamp at all. The output is determined strictly by the input times the gain, which is -100/10. The pot and 22R just constitute a passive load to the opamp but don't affect its gain equation.

The simplified formula for the output resistance of the inverting amplifier is:
\$R_{out} = \frac{R_{o}} {1 + A_{ol} * \frac{R1}{R1+R2}}\$
with \$R_{out}\$ being the output resistance of the inverting amp, \$R_{o}\$ the internal output resistance of the op-amp and \$A_{ol}\$ the open loop gain of the op-amp.

The detailed derivation of \$R_{out}\$ can be found here:
https://masteringelectronicsdesign.com/the-non-inverting-amplifier-output-resistance/
The output impedance of the op-amp stage is close to zero at low frequencies but increases when frequency goes up. At very high frequencies, where the open loop gain is close to zero, \$R_{out}\$ is on par with \$R_{o}\$.

For the sim model of a LM741 (TI), \$R_{out} = R_{o}\$ is measured at 10 MHz with a network analyzer to be around 182 Ohm. The open loop gain \$A_{ol}\$ of the op-amp at this frequency is 0.026.

\$R_{out} = R_{o}\$ measured with the \$\frac {V_{out}} {2}\$ method is close to the calculated value of 181 Ohm. Loaded with 182 Ohm, the output voltage is very close to half of the unloaded value of 0.475 mV.

At 50 kHz, with \$A_{ol}= 19.4\$, the output resitance \$R_{out}\$ of the amplifier is about 70 Ohm for an unloaded output voltage of 17.4mV and not far from the calculated value of 66 Ohm.

Thank you so much Raonoke, this is exactly what i have been looking for, but can you explain to me why at low frequency the output resistance doesnt appear?

Also since Vo = -10Vin, and suppose the frequency of Vin is 1kHz thus the Zo is still very close to zero as it appears my probes 's voltages doesn't change, so how can i get the exact value of that impedance, although i change the value of the pot, the voltage doesnt really change.

The Vo = -10Vin won't change until you get to very high frequencies where the opamp just craps out. If you want to attenuate low frequency signals you need to move your potentiometer to somewhere else in the circuit. If the 100K feedback resistor were a potentiometer for instance you could sweep gain from 0 to -10. You could also leave the pot where it is and take the output from the wiper, although the output impedance will vary with pot location. Putting a pot in series with R2 could work too. If you must use a 1K pot you'll have to lower the other resistors accordingly.

The question doesn't make much sense, since negative feedback will cause the op-amp to produce exactly:
$$ V_O = -V_{IN} \frac{R_{22}}{R_{18}} $$
This is true regardless of the output impedance of the op-amp. The op-amp continually adjusts \$V_O\$ up or down until the potential at its two inputs are equal, zero in this case. If output \$V_O\$ is too low to satisfy that condition, the op-amp "pulls it up" harder, and vice versa, effectively overcoming any output driver shortcomings such as impedance.
The first circuit below is your amplifier without any modification, and below that is the same circuit, but with an additional resistance introduced into the op-amp's output path:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
As you can see, the overall output (shown on voltmeters VM1 and VM2) is as expected:
$$ V_O = -V_{IN} \frac{R_{22}}{R_{18}} = -(+1V) \times \frac{100k\Omega}{10k\Omega} = -10V $$
In the second circuit, though, I am also measuring the the op-amp's own direct output, just prior to the artificially introduced output impedance R6. You'll notice it's slightly bigger at -11V. In other words, the op-amp is producing whatever output is necessary to ensure that the above formula remains true.
Let's increase the load on the second circuit's output even more, by setting R7 to 500Ω instead of 1kΩ. This should double the current through that load:

simulate this circuit
VM3 shows the op-amp "pulling down harder" in order to overcome the increased load, but the overall output remains -10V exactly.
We define output impedance to be the ratio of change in output voltage in response to a change in output current:
$$ R_{OUT}=\frac{\Delta V_{OUT}}{\Delta I_{OUT}} $$
Here output voltage remained -10V under all circumstances, but when we halved the load resistance we doubled the current:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Delta V_{OUT} &= (-10V) - (-10V) = 0V \\ \\
\Delta I_{OUT} &= \frac{-10V}{500\Omega} - \frac{-10V}{1k\Omega} = (-20mA) - (-10mA) = -10mA \\ \\
R_{OUT} &= \frac{\Delta V_{OUT}}{\Delta I_{OUT}} = \frac{0V}{-10mA} = 0\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
The negative feedback implemented by the potential divider formed by R18 and R22 is causing the output impedance of the system to be effectively zero, regardless of the actual output impedance of the op-amp itself.

This doesn't mean that the op-amp itself has zero output impedance, it means only that a system with negative feedback effectively has zero output impedance.
Of course the op-amp has output impedance, but since you don't have access to its internals, you can't measure it when the loop is closed like this. You can only measure the op-amp's actual output impedance in a open loop.
This is notoriously difficult to do; the op-amp's open loop gain is so high that you will need to apply a potential difference between its inverting and non-inverting inputs precise to microvolts, and keep it stable while you adjust the load and measure \$\frac{\Delta V_{OUT}}{\Delta I_{OUT}}\$.

Thanks Simon, well im more interested in the last part about calculating the internal output resistance, because thats what im tasked to do, infinite thanks again!
